# Cannot read property 'count' of undefined json parsing

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script in google apps script that calls the Facebook graph api and then parses the data to a google sheet. Everything was working fine until two day ago where i started getting the  "Cannot read property 'count' of undefined" error.

When i call the API i get this back

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "permalink_url": "url?substory_index=0",
         "created_time": "time",
         "message": "message"
            "shares": {
            "count": 455
         },
         "reactions": {
            "data": [

            ],
            "summary": {
               "total_count": 555,
               "viewer_reaction": "NONE"
            }
         },
         "comments": {
            "data": [

            ],
            "summary": {
               "order": "ranked",
               "total_count": 345,
               "can_comment": false
            }
```

But then when the script tries to run it gets the  "Cannot read property 'count' of undefined" error. 
The error refers to this line on my script

`rows.push([new Date(),data.created_time,data.message,data.permalink_url,data.shares.count,data.reactions.summary.total_count,data.comments.summary.total_count`

It is only broken for the data.share.count and data.reactions.summary.total_Count.

Anyone have an idea to what might suddenly went wrong?

Entire script

```
function getAPIdata() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheetname');
  var range = sheet.getRange("A:C");
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("API CALL");
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var dataSet = dataAll.data;
  var rows = [],
    data;
  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([new Date(),data.created_time,data.message,data.permalink_url,
               data.reactions.summary.total_count
               ,data.comments.summary.total_count,data.insights.data[1].values[0].value,data.insights.data[2].values[0].value,data.insights.data[3].values[0].value,data.insights.data[0].values[0].value['link clicks'],data.insights.data[0].values[0].value['photo view'],data.insights.data[0].values[0].value['other clicks'],data.insights.data[0].values[0].value['video play'],data.insights.data[4].values[0].value,data.insights.data[5].values[0].value,data.insights.data[6].values[0].value,data.insights.data[7].values[0].value["like"],data.insights.data[7].values[0].value["love"],data.insights.data[7].values[0].value["wow"],data.insights.data[7].values[0].value["haha"],data.insights.data[7].values[0].value["sorry"]]); //your JSON entities here
  }
  Logger.log(rows)
  //sheet.getRange(getlastRow() + 1, 1, rows.length, 2).setValues(rows);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rows.length, 22).setValues(rows);





/**
 * Removes duplicate rows from the current sheet.
 */

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetname');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  data.reverse(); //reverses the row order.

  var last=sheet.getLastRow();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    //Logger.log(i);
    var row = data[i];
    //Logger.log(row[5]);
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      //Logger.log(newData[j][3]);
      if(row[3] == newData[j][3]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }

  newData.reverse(); // reverses your data back to its original order.

  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  }
//  
  //
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Refined Answer:
You can skip posts without shares **AND** reactions in your dataSet for loop before you do the rows.push() call.

```
for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) 
{
    data = dataSet[i];

    //skip post with no shares
    if (data.shares == undefined) 
    { 
        continue; 
    }

    //skip post with no reactions
    if (data.reactions == undefined)
    {
        continue;
    }

    //rows.push (...
}
```

If you want to only include posts that have either shares **OR** reactions then you will need to initialise the count values to 0 rather than skipping them up front (and then check if both counts are 0 to skip):

```
//Set share count to 0 for post with no shares
if (data.shares == undefined) 
{ 
    data.shares = {};
    data.shares.count = 0; 
}

//Set reactions count to 0 for post with no reactions
if (data.reactions == undefined) 
{ 
    data.reactions = {};
    data.reactions.summary = {}
    data.reactions.summary.total_count = 0;
}


//skip posts that don't contain shares OR reactions
if (data.shares.count == 0 && data.reactions.summary.total_count == 0)
{
    continue;
}
```

//Original Answer:
It looks like the data contains an array of values, whereas this might not have been the case previously if your code was working before.

I can't see the share count in the incomplete/invalid data sample you supplied but it looks like you now need to reference the reactions summary count as:

```
data[0]['reactions']['summary']['total_count']
```

And I'm guessing that the share count reference should possibly look like this:

```
data[0]['shares']['count']
```

But I would expect your other references to the data values to have stopped working as well as the reactions and share counts and your other references will probably need to be updated to the data[0][.. form as well.

Comment: Hey @RichardMc. Thanks for you answer. I edited the original code to show you share count. (Did a bad job at copy pasting)

The json seems exactly the same as it did before with the exception of those two things breaking. 

I tried what you said but i had no luck unfortunately.

Every other reference works perfectly fine

Comment: Okay, thanks Andreas, that does help to confirm my assumption but the data sample is still an incomplete structure. Anyway I think I can see enough to know that you are getting an array back, so your references will need to change to account for that as I've mentioned in my answer above. I hope that helps you figure it out.

Comment: I don't think that's the case as all the other references work perfect. Still can't figure out what's wrong though.

Comment: Hey @Richard. Found the solution after all. There was a post that was deleted so there was no entry for reactions or shares. That created the problem.

Comment: Ha ha, that's cool Andreas. I was just processing that as a possibility while I was having my lunch! That explains why the shares were missing from your example data. Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Well almost. Now i need to find out a way to skip that post or exclude it. Any ideas on that?

Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Something like this? 

Check if data.shares is defined, otherwise initialise it {} and set .count to 0 or continue to skip it if you are processing this in a loop ...

if (data.shares == undefined)
{
  data.shares = {};
  data.shares.count = 0;
  //or continue; if you are in a loop?
}

Comment: @Andreas I've refined my answer with the code from my last comment so that you can see the code better with the syntax highlighting and indentation.

Comment: kind of a noob here as you might have figured. I upload the entire script i have in the original question. Could you maybe show me where i should put the code so that if the shares are undefined then that post should be skipped? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Andreas Please see my refined answer, I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @Andreas Awesome, glad to help! Please accept my working answer as the solution, thanks.